# Debugging NodeJS Azure function in a docker container from VS Code

Tags: typescript, azure, docker, azure-functions, remote-debugging

I cannot get remote debugging up & running for my NodeJS Azure function in a docker container.

**Setup:**

I followed the tutorial from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container?tabs=acr%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-typescript) and created a sample HTTP triggered function

```
func init --worker-runtime node --language typescript --docker
func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel anonymous
```

It created the following folder structure

[image: folder structure od sample azure function]

And the generated docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build
```

I started the container with the turned-on Node debugger

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -p 9233:9233 -e NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect=0.0.0.0:9233 -it af-docker
```

From the container output, I can see that the debugger is listening on port `9233`

```
info: Host.Function.Console[0]
  Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9233/77214a10-aeb3-47e0-ac5a-2dcd4f021008
info: Host.Function.Console[0]
  For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

So I edited the `launch.json` file to add support for remote debugging

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
        "remoteRoot": "/site/wwwroot/dist/src/functions",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\functions",
        "port": 9233,
        "address": "localhost",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result:**

When I run the debugger (`F5`), I can see from the container output that the debugger is attached

```
info: Host.Function.Console[0]
  Debugger attached.
```

However, I get the following error in the debug console and breakpoints are not hit/binded

```
LanguageWorkerConsoleLogWorker b62c4a73-8509-4a3f-a496-cca18cb56bb0 connecting on 127.0.0.1:42681
worker-bundle.js:2
Could not read source map for file:///azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\azure-functions-host\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///home/site/wwwroot/dist/src/functions/HttpExample.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\src\functions\HttpExample.js.map'
```

Both paths are invalid (`C:\azure-functions-host\**`) and (`C:\home\site\**`) and do not exist on the local machine. I suppose there is some misconfiguration in the `launch.json` file, but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not read source map for file:///azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\azure-functions-host\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js.map' Could not read source map for file:///home/site/wwwroot/dist/src/functions/HttpExample.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\src\functions\HttpExample.js.map'

You are getting this error because debugger is trying to look for `dist\src\functions` folder in your folder structure.

To generate `dist` folder, run the commands in the following order-

```
 1. func init --worker-runtime node --language typescript --docker
 2. func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel anonymous
 3. npm install
 4. npm start
```

You will be able to see below folder structure.

[image]

Then I made the same changes which you did in `launch.json` file.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "remoteRoot": "/site/wwwroot/dist/src/functions",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\functions",
            "port": 9233,
            "address": "localhost",
            "sourceMaps": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

I started the debugger and got the expected output.

[image]

[image]